# How to set time zone as float in Zing Chart?

Tags: charts, timezone, dst, zingchart

I use ZingChart to show data as a chart. In the char, I show the data following a time which I get from the server. ZingChart is set as default to follow client time.

I found we can set time zone in a chart only as integer value. However, some time zone are UTC+10:30, UTC+04:30...

So how can we set time zone to ZingChart showing correct time? And if that day has Daylight Saving Time, how should I correct it.

[JSON scripts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9Ngb.png)

Comment: Would you be able to show the json and javascript of how you are configuring your chart? Are you using ZingChart to handle the querying from your server using the `refresh` property or are you handling that separately?

Comment: Thanks for your attention!

Comment: In my sence, the server in UTC +1: windhoek and the client in UTC +7:Ha Noi and Daylight Saving Time began... Belows are JSON script: "graphset":[
    {
        "scale-x":{
            "max-labels":7,
            "zooming":true,
            "min-value":1445884200000,
            "step":3600000,
            "transform":{
                "type":"date",
                "all":"%M %d,%Y<br>%h:%i %A",
                "guide":{
                    "visible":false
                },
                "item":{
                    "visible":false
                }
            }
        },
 }

Comment: @mike-schultz please see my answer below.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately it appears that ZingChart only supports whole-hour time zone offsets. Not only does this not account for time zones with fixed fractional-hour offsets, but it also doesn't properly account for time zones that use daylight saving time.

The example [in the documentation](http://www.zingchart.com/docs/features/scales/) says:

> ... For example, to set the timezone to Pacific Time, you would add: `"timezone":-8`.

This is incorrect, as Pacific time is only at UTC-8 during standard time.  When it's in daylight time, it uses UTC-7.

This is a common mistake.  See "Time Zone != Offset" in [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).  My recommendation to the ZingChart developers would be:

1. Anywhere you support `timezone:-8` you should also support fractional hour offsets such as `timezone:5.5` or `timezone:8.75`.
2. You should also support named time zone identifiers such as `"America/Los_Angeles"`.  To make them work, you'll need to provide a function that the developer can hook into.  Don't try to implement the function directly, as there are [several libraries already available](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15171030/634824) for this.  For example, a developer might combine ZingChart with moment-timezone by writing something like:

   ```
   zingchart.fnTZOffset = function(timestamp, timeZone) {
       return moment(timestamp).tz(timeZone).utcOffset() / 60;
   }
   ```

   ZingChart would invoke this function when timezone was a string and would apply the resulting offset to the specific data point.

Without support from ZingChart, there's not much you can do to properly support time zones.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I think you right but unfortunately, ZingChart only support hour offsets as integer. I used expression: (local - utctime) / 3600 to get timezone. But if It has daylight saving time, I will have trouble. While C++ not support get timezone.

Comment: Thanks Matt, we'll definitely work on supporting fractional hours and come up with an easier way to support time zones so it's easier for end-users.

Answer (score 0):

One other solution to the Daylight Savings time issue some ZingChart users have mentioned in the past is MomentJS. http://momentjs.com